# Duplicates in SQL when using DISTINCT

Tags: sql, join, select, duplicates, distinct

Not sure why I keep getting duplicates with this query. It should be easy, but for some reason I just cannot figure it out.

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    STUFF((SELECT 
               ';  ' + 
               CASE
                   WHEN staff.lastname IS NOT NULL 
                       THEN UPPER(REPLACE(RTRIM(staff.lastname), ' ', '') + ', ' + RTRIM(staff.firstname))
                       ELSE UPPER('Not Assigned')
               END
           FROM 
               ca_case_assign ca 
           JOIN 
               staff ON staff.username = ca.staffusername
           JOIN 
               tbl_case c on ca.appid = c.col_caseid
           WHERE 
               ca.clientusername = c.col_username 
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [CaseManager]
```

and this is the result that I get:

```
LOCALSTAFF, THERESA;  LOCALSTAFF, THERESA;  O'MALLEY, ELLEN;  STAFF, STATE;  STAFF, STATE;  STAFF, STATE;  STAFF, STATE;  STAFF, STATE;  STAFF, BC;  STAFF, BC;  STAFF, BC;  STAFF, BC;  STAFF, BC;  STAFF, BC;  STAFF, BC;
```

Which is obviously incorrect.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Please provide an example data set that you use with this query to make this a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also please add a specific tag for the DBMS implementation being used (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.)

Comment: try adding a sort on this - UPPER(REPLACE(RTRIM(staff.lastname), ' ', '') + ', ' + RTRIM(staff.firstname))...and put the distinct on the INNER query

Comment: You select a scalar value, there's nothing to distinct in a single row. You need to put `distinct` into inner query

Comment: Also for SQL Server 2017+ you may use [`string_agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which is more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner query should have the distinct instead:

```
SELECT
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT 
           ';  ' + 
           CASE
               WHEN staff.lastname IS NOT NULL 
                   THEN UPPER(REPLACE(RTRIM(staff.lastname), ' ', '') + ', ' + RTRIM(staff.firstname))
                   ELSE UPPER('Not Assigned')
           END
       FROM 
           ca_case_assign ca 
       JOIN 
           staff ON staff.username = ca.staffusername
       JOIN 
           tbl_case c on ca.appid = c.col_caseid
       WHERE 
           ca.clientusername = c.col_username 
       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [CaseManager]
```

Comment: That helped get rid of the duplicates, but it is still coming back with a bunch of "Case Managers" and it should not have that many. I don't think the data is the issue, I think it might have something to do with the joins